# VS2015 F# compilation error Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets

Tags: visual-studio, f#

Please help !!!!

I don't know how it exactly happened, but my VS2015 looks f*cked up and I can't compile my projects anymore...

I just remember excluding by mistake a .fsx file from the project in solution explorer and tried to reinsert it again

but maybe this isn't the cause, and its due to some automatic update ?
when i compile my program i get this error

I tried creating a new project, reinstalling Nuget packages in the new project, copied/pasted the old source .fs files into new files in the new project, but i still get the error

i don't think it has anything to do with Seq.tail, anything other program will have something underlined as well, but the Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets warnings remain

[image: error1]
[image: error2]

I'm thinking about reinstalling everything but will it solve the problem ???
I feel really desperate... Thanks very much to anyone who can help

Comment: Check what version of FSharp.Core is referenced. `Seq.tail` was added in F# 4.0. It happened to me several times that a NuGet package downgraded FSharp.Core to version 3.x causing similar errors. If that's the case, you can use NuGet to update it back to 4.x